# d3.js - Irregular layout on column chart when columns represent months

Tags: d3.js

Check out this quick and dirty example that I threw together: http://zoopoetics.com/d3/irregular_layout.html

d3 is doing its job admirably, laying out the columns at irregular intervals because months are of irregular durations. As we all know, a month can last from 28 to 31 days.

Thing is, the irregular layout is unsettling to the eye. I want the columns to lay out at regular pixel intervals along the horizontal axis.

Looked all over the googles for an answer and found very little about this problem, which suggests that I may be missing something obvious.

Has anyone else been here and surmounted the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to use the time x axis but render the bars against a different scale of lets say 365/12 intervals.
The x scale I think should have the month name labels in the middle of each month as well as a tick at the middle:

[Here is my version of your file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8561342/d3/t1.html)

here